# How to join a model and get a name from second model via joining

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a students table and a university table.

I seem to be unable to retrieve the university name based on the university_id the student has

Database:

students:

```
id, first_name, last_name, university_id
0, bob, jones, 12
1, Tim, Smith, 13
```

university:

```
id,   name
12  Harvard
13  Stanton
14  N/A
```

Models.py

```py
from django.db import models

class University(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "University"
        verbose_name_plural = "Universities"

    #__unicode__
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Student"
        verbose_name_plural = "Students"
    #__str__
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

views.py

```py
class View_all_apiview(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        students_q = Student.objects.all().prefetch_related('university')

        return JsonResponse(list(students_q.values()), safe=False)
```

I tried getting the university name using students_q.name, but that gives an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Rest Framework. So you should use a serializer to determine what fields to display.

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    university = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'university')
```

Here, `StringRelatedField` uses the `__str__` method of the related model, which in your case uses the name.

Now your view can just be:

```
class AllStudents(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Student.objects.all().select_related('university')
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
```

Note, as you want to follow the forward relationship, you use `select_related` not `prefetch_related`.

Comment: Thanks this worked, I had to import generics and then use generics.ListAPIView. What if I added a new column to university called founded_year, how would I display that. could I just add the field name to the fields? (and add to model first)

Comment: You can use [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) to point to an arbitrary field on the target model. But if you're including multiple related fields, at this point you probably want to use a [nested serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).